# How to bind multiple events of the same type to a single element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [add or subtract functions from onSubmit event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982087/add-or-subtract-functions-from-onsubmit-event-handler)

I'm having trouble binding two blur events to the same element.  The second function that I'm binding is overriding the first function that was bound to the element.  What is the proper way to bind multiple events to the same element?  I'm using pure JavaScript. No jQuery.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joeljoeljoel/CRGHt/

I would like both of the functions to fire `onblur`. The order doesn't matter for my particular situation, however, I am interested in knowing if I can control the order.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (but note that you need to do a feature test to see if that's available, as IE uses `attachEvent` instead):

```
var message = document.getElementById('message');
message.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    alert('blur function one');
});
message.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    alert('blur function two');
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CRGHt/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just combine those in one?

```
function prepare_function() {
    var message = document.getElementById('message');
    message.onblur = function() {
        alert('blur function one');
        alert('blur function two');
    }
}
```