# Javascript Ajax DOM add onsubmit to a form

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

In my project i create using Ajax DOM a POST form.
I have to add an onsubmit method, i try:

```
var impform = document.createElement("FORM");
impform.method = "post";
impform.onsubmit = "/import_templ";
```

but wher i load my webpage form are created ok and method was POST but there isn't the onsubmit method.

[image]

How can i add my onsubmit method to the form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `onsubmit` is a method, here you have assigned it to a string, so it cannot be executed. Perhaps you mean to use `action` instead of `onsubmit`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849659/adding-onsubmit-to-a-form-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned to the `onsubmit` property (or attached with `addEventListener`, which is the modern approach) needs to be a **function**.

You are assigning a string.

```js
function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.style.background = '#aaf';
}

var impform = document.createElement("form");
impform.method = "post";
impform.action = "http://example.com/";
impform.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type="submit";

impform.appendChild(btn);
document.body.appendChild(impform);
```

Answer (score 0):

for example.
DOM form/input access and click button submit.

```
<form method="post" name="form_test">
  <button type="button" name="submit_test" >test</button>
</form>
<script>
document.form_test.method = "post";
document.form_test.action = "/import_templ";
document.form_test.addEventListener("click", submit);
function submit () {
  document.form_test.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

In believe that /import_templ is the road you want to access so you have to put this in the action of the form not onsubmit

impform.method = "/import_templ";

then change you button type to "submit"
IMPORT THIS TEMPLATE